# Convert String to Data base HTTP.UTF8 in swift

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, utf-8

in send request to web Service my parameter string should encoding base UTF8 , there is my code for get data base UTF8 encoding :

```
  let postData
            = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
            //param is NSDictionary 
   let jsonString = NSString(data: postData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
   let pair = "action=payment&key=hmn@$Q*$GD4@!$#&input=\(jsonString)"
   let post = pair.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = post
```

there is java code in android :

```
 pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "payment"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "hmn@$Q&*$GD4@!$#"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("input", item.toString()));

        try {
            httpGet.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Exception_Code = 1;

        }
```

some parameter in input key encrypt with MD5 and tripleDes, i can't get response from web service because in encode base UTF8 in swift + character in encrypt data change with space , how can encode base HTTP.UTF_8 in swift. 
in swift :

```
"ExpDate" : "ZIT5KR2 4Mk="
```

in android :

```
"ExpDate":"ZIT5KR2+4Mk="
```

how can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand as you don't explain what `"ExpDate":"ZIT5KR2+4Mk="` is. In which part is it contained? I assume *ExpDate* is a property *param* dictionary that's serialized into JSON. I further assume that the plus character is the original character after the Base64 encoding and wasn't inserted when the URL request was built.

Your server obviously expects a POST request with URL encoded form data. This kind of request is natively supported by Android (`UrlEncodedFormEntity`) but not by iOS. To achieve the same, you cannot just concatenate the key/value pairs. You must properly URL encode them as well.

To that end, I propose the following `URLRequest` extension:

```
import Foundation

extension URLRequest {

    private static let alloweCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 -_.*")

    public mutating func setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: [String: String?]) {

        var encodedParameters = ""

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            if !encodedParameters.isEmpty {
                encodedParameters += "&"
            }

            encodedParameters += URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: key)
            encodedParameters += "="
            if let value = value {
                encodedParameters += URLRequest.urlEncoded(value: value)
            }
        }

        self.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        self.httpBody = encodedParameters.data(using: .utf8)
    }


    private static func urlEncoded(value: String) -> String {

        return value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: alloweCharacters)!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    }


}
```

It can be used like this (tested in Playground):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://somehost.com/someservice")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let jsonString = "{ \"ExpDate\" : \"ZIT5KR2+4Mk=\", \"SomeString\" : \"%=&\" }"
var params = [ "action": "payment", "key": "hmn@$Q&*$GD4@!$#", "input": jsonString]
request.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: params)
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: My first code might not have covered all cases correctly. I've added a new version with a custom character set and explicit conversion of spaces to the plus character.